# How pass the string to <T> in reflection

Tags: c#, generics, system.reflection

I have a this function---

```
public static T parseEntity<T>(Object source, Object target)
```

this function parse the Entity in source to Model in target. My intention is call him self like this:

```
EntityFactory.parseEntity<T>(prop.GetValue(source, null), objectAux);
```

my problem is the parameter `<T>`. I have a name of type as string.

Comment: I don't understand what the problem you are having is.

Comment: I agree with @ScottChamberlain. Maybe you could give a more complete example? Or state what results you get and how they differ from the ones you expected? Have a look at [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).